# How can I prevent someone with a stolen device from accessing my village?

Tags: clash-of-clans

A year back my iPod got stolen. On the ipod I had Clash of Clans and as a result I decided to use a "Find my iPhone" app and check the box where it says "erase all data and personal info from this iPod once it gets connected to wifi".

My problem is that now that I have a new phone and am still playing Clash of Clans with the same account. It seems, though, that someone has access to my village because when i get on the game I have my army camps full of goblins and stuff like that.

I need help on how to solve this because I have spent 100 dollars so far on this base and I really don't want to erase it. Is there something I can do to keep the other person out of my account/village?

Comment: Woah, calm down.  I'm not sure if we can help you with this.

Comment: Did you try changing your account password?

Comment: Yes, i have try changing everything. But somehow he stills is able to change things around.

Comment: in reality he shouldn't be able to enter your account if you change your password

Comment: Well i did some research and what i have read so far is that once my village is on his device theres nothing i can do to stop him from getting on it all the time. Which sucks :/

Comment: on the find my iphone app you should be able to reset the iphone, this should remove the device from your itunes account. Another thing is that it is possible that someone else has in fact hacked your game.

Comment: Change your Apple account password (and consequently your Game Center password) then reset your device remotely again

Comment: Trouble is that even if you reset your password, the other device can still have a "Keep me logged in" option checked, so the only way would be to remotely reset the phone.

Answer (score 7):

You write a message to SuperCell and they will ask you some info like below

- When did you start playing on this account?
- Where (which city) did you create the account?
- When did you notice that your account was compromised?
- What device(s) do you use to play the account?

Answer (score 1):

If you sync your game via your Facebook profile instead of your Game Center the game will prompt you once in a while to re-log since Facebook's authentication has a lifespan of a few hours to days while Game Center is account bound.

Things like erasing your device can only be done if you use iCloud's Find My Device function, not via your phone company.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your old phone company and tell them to stop your old phone from working because its stolen. So they will erase everything in your old phone. And the one who stole it wont be able to use it or even sell it because everything erased from it. And its reported stolen. They even blocks it I think. So he will not be able to open it even

Comment: This only possible for some phone companies.