# Stop sharing my COC-account

Tags: clash-of-clans

L. S.,
I've been playing COC for circa one year. My nephew plays the game a little longer, but when he bought a new cell phone he couldn't switch his COC-account from his Android device to his new Iphone. He was quite sad because he thought he had to start all over again. However, it seemed possible to let him play on his Iphone via my COC account. Unknown of the consequences, I naively agreed to let him play on my COC-account; but now I regret my decision because he does silly things on my COC-account. For example:

- base forming the words "your mother is a bitch!!!";
- participate in a troll base;
- offensive language in the chat;

Et cetera. Et cetera...

I asked him several times to behave and every time he promised me to stop his bad habits. I think he doesn't understand he does something wrong, but I don't want to correct him any longer. I'm not his dad and after three months I've lost my patience. I want him to leave from my account...

My question is if there is an easy way to get rid of him? Of course I can ask him to stop playing on my account, but I want to be sure he can't access my account in the future.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160862/how-can-i-prevent-someone-with-a-stolen-device-from-accessing-my-village

Comment: Make him reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is backed up on the cloud first!

1. Go under settings
2. Tap Apps
3. Go and find where Clash of Clans Application is found at and tap it.
4. There should be a button saying Clear Data, or Clear Cache.  I'd recommend doing both but Clearing the Data is necessary.

When you start CoC up again it should go back to the Tutorial Level.

Answer (score 0):

You could close your account and start anew but I suggest contacting COC moderator or clan leader for other options. Hope this helps.